# Akka getting dead letter count for shutdown routine

Tags: akka

I have an actor that aggregates an arbitrary number of sub-actor messages. The sub-actors call each other in order like:

```
system.actorSelection(s"/user/$groupId-${index + 1}*") ! Declare
```

This gave me the idea of using dead letter counts for my shutdown routine to trigger after X letters and some hardcoded sleep. Akka seemingly does not aggregate after a point given the log below:

```
[...] was not delivered. [10] dead letters encountered, no more dead letters will be logged.[...]
```

But this tells me there is a reliable way to set up a listener to count how many dead letters are generated. What would be the best approach here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in documentation :

> As described at Stopping actors, messages queued when an actor
>   terminates or sent after its death are re-routed to the dead letter
>   mailbox, which by default will publish the messages wrapped in
>   DeadLetter. [...] it’s still possible to subscribe to them explicitly:

```
import akka.actor.AllDeadLetters
system.eventStream.subscribe(listener, classOf[AllDeadLetters])
```

The listener being an Actor that can receive `DeadLetter` as a message in its behaviour (`receive` method)

```
def receive = {
    case d: DeadLetter => println(d) // You can implement your count here
  }
```

More info: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/event-bus.html#dead-letters